# Unable to post to aspnet webapi using angular http

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular-http

I have created a simple webapi controller.

```
        // POST request api to get a string base64 image, store it and returns its name.
    public string Post([FromBody]string image)
    {
        if (image == null)
            return "No image sent";

        // Generating random file name using the current date and time and random text
        string fileName = "image-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + Path.ChangeExtension(
            Path.GetRandomFileName(),
            ".jpg"
        );

        // If the directory does not exist create a new one
        if (!Directory.Exists(@".\uploads\"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo DI = Directory.CreateDirectory(@".\uploads\");
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(@".\uploads\" + fileName, Convert.FromBase64String(image));
        return "Submitted as File: " + fileName;
    }
```

When I send a post request through postman, it works as fine and returns the string "Submitted as File ..."
But when I try it in Angular I get the following error.

OPTIONS http://example.com/Api/Image/Index 405 (Method Not Allowed)

My angular service:

```
  getResult(base64image) {
//Where base64image is a string.
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post('http://example.com/Api/Image/Index', base64image, options)
.map(res => res);
```

}

I know that it has something to with cors. But it is just a simple api.

Comment: Hi .. I'm not sure it has something with CORS .. 405 means the method you're asking is not allowed .. the reason could be multiple .. or you call in a wrong way the api (the url) .. can you check the newtork tab in crhome? ..and chek if everytinh is fine?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi You were right thank you. Angular is sending an options request instead of a post request.